# The datum is not an example of schema- Avro Python

Tags: python-3.x, schema, avro

`avro.schema.Parse` works fine. The values to the data are read correctly. But looks like data and schema doesn't sync in.

I get the error:

```
The datum {datafromfile{whole bunch fields from data}, DATE = value, file_name = value}
```

is not an example of the schema from the .avsc file.

My schema is a nested avro schema. ***The last field of type 'info' contains some fields of type strings but not all the fields as in the data coming in.

Is this mismatch between fields causing an issue?

Below is my `.avsc` file.

```
{
   "type": "record",
   "name": "header_data",
   "doc": "A  list  of strings.",
   "fields": [
            {"name": "DATE", "type": "string"},
            {"name": "file_name", "type": "string"},        
            {"name": "info", "type": "info"}]
}
```

Comment: please add your code. .

Comment: `writer = avro.io.DatumWriter(schema)
  bytes_writer = io.BytesIO()
  encoder = avro.io.BinaryEncoder(bytes_writer)
  for test in test_data:
   writer.write({"DATE": data['DATE'], "file_name" : data['file_name'], "info": data['info'] }, encoder)
  raw_bytes = bytes_writer.getvalue()
  producer.send(topic, raw_bytes)`